# Snapshot in Futurebuilder is not null but still getting snapshot.hasData as false

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am calling two futures in the Futurebuilder in which one of them is returning the complete data but the on returning an empty list as a list of data is expected but for now that data is empty. Even though both of these functions completes successfully still snapshot.hasData shows false.

I have printed the data obtained from the function; one function was returning the expected data, and one function returned the empty list as the database doesn't have any data to return.

[image]

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg